# Javascript: Add property to prototype with class expression

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, properties, prototype

How to add a property to prototype with class expression. I can do it with the older method:

```
function Example(){}
Example.prototype.property = 'PROPERTY'
```

But I don't know how can I do the same thing with class expression

Comment: `class` is only synthetic sugar so under the hood it works as in Your example

Comment: You cannot do it *inside* the `class` body, there is no syntax for that. Only for defining methods (and getters/setters).

Comment: Usually, one does not set data values in the prototype unless they are read-only.  If you ever set a new value for the data value in the prototype, it will affect all instances which is usually not what you want.  If you ever a new value for the data value on an instance, it will "hide" and "override" the prototype value.  It's way more common to just initialize a property on the object in your constructor and not put data on the prototype.

Comment: I actually wanted don't waste memory by big size properties during each instance process. The other hand, I wanted make that with class expression. But now I suppose there is no syntax for what I wish based on your answers and comments

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it the same way :)
[image]